# ROR 2.x dynamic partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

In an action, I need to dynamically generate a partial with encoded content and display it as a popup via data-uri:

**Controller**

```
def dashboard
    @surprise = get_deal(srand % current_user.dob_year)
end

def get_deal(magic_number)
    if magic_number < 500
      return "<h5>You have won a voucher #{VoucherFactory.unused_in_the_queue}</h5>"
    end
end
```

Now, in view I need something like `:partial=>@surprise` without saving the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply render the @surprise in view:

```
<div id="surprise-area" ..>
    <%= @surprise %>
</div>
```